# JSON.NET Conflicting property name when using JsonPropertyAttribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a following JSON string:

```
{
    "items" : "1",
    "itemdetails": 
    [
        {
            "id" : "5",
            "name:" "something"
        }
    ]
}
```

`items` represents item count and actual items are in `itemdetails`.

I would like to deserialize this to a class like this:

```
class Parent
{
    JsonProperty("itemdetails")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

However, when I call

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(inputString)
```

I get a `JsonSerializationException` that string `"1"` cannot be converted to `IEnumerable<Item>`. I guess the parser is trying to deserialize `items` from JSON into `Items` property because they match by name. And it's ignoring the `JsonProperty` attribute.

Is this by design? Any workarounds? Thanks!

**EDIT**

As Brian Rogers commented, this code as it is works correctly. I figured that I missed to add a piece of the puzzle.

The problem is if I want to use private collection setters and initialize those properties from the constructor.

```
public Parent(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    this.Items = items;
}
```

This is causing the exception to be thrown. What should I do here? Annotate constructor arguments somehow? Or use `ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor`?

Comment: I deleted my answer since you stated the reason in the question. give the parser a place to store items to.

Comment: @Johannes: I don't need that property, I would like to skip it when parsing. Is there no other way?

Comment: @lukeguy It's fine.  If a property is not defined in your class, it will be skipped by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues.  First, your `JsonProperty` attribute is malformed.

You have:

```
JsonProperty("itemdetails"]
```

It should be:

```
[JsonProperty("itemdetails")]
```

Secondly, part of your JSON is invalid.

You have this:

```
 "name:" "something",
```

It should be:

```
 "name" : "something"
```

After fixing both of those problems, it worked just fine for me.  Here is the test program I used:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""items"" : ""1"",
            ""itemdetails"": 
            [
                {
                    ""id"" : ""5"",
                    ""name"" : ""something""
                }
            ]
        }";

        Parent parent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json);
        foreach (Item item in parent.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " (" + item.Id + ")");
        }
    }
}

class Parent
{
    [JsonProperty("itemdetails")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
something (5)
```

**EDIT**

OK, so if I understand you correctly, your *real* Parent class actually looks like this:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
    }

    [JsonProperty("itemdetails")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

In this case you have a couple of choices to get it to work:

You either can change the name of the parameter in your constructor to match the JSON, e.g.:

```
    public Parent(IEnumerable<Item> itemdetails)
    {
        this.Items = itemdetails;
    }
```

OR you can add a separate private constructor for Json.Net to use:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private Parent()
    {
    }

    [JsonProperty("itemdetails")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I was typing an example out of my head directly in the browser, that's why I have typos. I'll fix them.

Comment: The fact remains that it works if you have your attributes correct (and the JSON is correct).  So I would check your code to make sure that you have not made a typo in the `JsonProperty` attribute on your "Items" property.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typos. I added an edit, parametrized constructor is the problem.

Comment: @lukeguy I've updated my answer to address your edit.